# query sql database via powershell - select distinct not returning values

Tags: sql, powershell, distinct

I'm hoping someone has a quick answer for this as I cannot find much online.

I am executing a sql command remotely via powershell. I have the script and it works but if I try a "select customer from customertable' it returns the values fine. if I run the query 'select distinct....' it returns no values.

Can the distinct command be run via powershell?

Comment: distinct is an SQL construct, not a powershell construct. If your SQL is fine, powershell should return the results just fine but you've left out that critical part from your question. `select distinct ... ` is not valid SQL.

Comment: please provide more example code from your script. also add the error message.

Comment: $UserSqlQuery = "select * from users"
$UserSqlQuery = "select distinct id from users"

First command returns all the rows, second command returns none.

Comment: Both commands return the correct values when executed in SQL

Comment: column id exist into your table? All values are null for id into your table? And how you test for know they are not return?

Comment: Both commands return values when run in sql. The first command returns the values, when I enter distinct it returns nothing. It's as if distinct cannot be used?

Comment: Can you post your complete script? Powershell in itself doesn't do SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a snippet of a much longer PS script I use to query different servers/instances to find the information I need.

```
function SQL_GetModules {
    param(
        [string]$DbName
    )

    $query = @"
        SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL BLAH BLAH BLAH
"@

    try {

        $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DBServer -Database $DbName -Query $query -querytimeout ([int]::MaxValue) -MaxCharLength ([int]::MaxValue) -DisableVariables

    }
    catch [System.Exception] {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        return -1
    }

    if (!$result) { return 0 }
    else {
        $Modules = @()

        foreach ($row in $result) {
            $Modules += $row.SYSA_Module
        }

        return $Modules
    }

}
```

If your query works in SQL and you pass it to the Invoke_SQLcmd and then run it does it work? AFAIK you dont need to use `Import-Module sqlps` with later versions of SQL as there is new PS SQL modules, that being said are these installed?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017